# SQL query with max date instance

Tags: mysql, sql, maxdate

Given the following table:

```
DATE      |ARRANGMENT_STATUS | CUSTOMER
----------+------------------+-------
2017-01-01|BROKEN            |0001
2017-02-01|OK                |0001
2017-03-01|BROKEN            |0001
```

How can I query the DB so result will give me the latest broken status( 2017-03-01) - I dont want to get broken status if they are not the latest ( 2017-01-01)

Hope it makes sence, 
thanks

Comment: table structure

Comment: Please put 4 spaces in front of your table and code so that it is formatted properly. You can also highlight the block and hit the code button. Please stop editting it back. You are clearly NOT improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all information in the row, you can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.arrangement_status = 'Broken'
order by t.date desc
limit 1;
```

If you only want the date, the JNevill's solution is fine.

Comment: Seems like limit is now giving me an error from SQL ad Excel ( Connecting to Data source: SELECT T.*
FROM T
WHERE T.C_STATUS = 'B'
ORDER BY T.ARRANGMENT_DATE DESC
LIMIT 1;

Comment: `LIMIT` is a fundamental part of MySQL.  If your database doesn't support it, then you probably have a different database and should tag your question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the max(date) for that status:

```
SELECT max(date) FROM table WHERE arrangement_status = 'Broken'
```